# Mysql: Select COUNT query with different conditions

Tags: mysql

How would a query look like that gets the count of items (oid) having active set to 1 AND having color red AND having color (black OR white)

My try

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
WHERE active=1 AND color='red' AND (color="black" OR color="white")
AND oid IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY oid
```

> **Notice**
> **The `oid IN (1,2,3,4)` must be in the query and MySQL 8 is not supported.**

| id | oid | color | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | red | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | black | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | white | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | red | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | black | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | green | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | red | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | green | 1 |
| 9 | 4 | red | 1 |
| 10 | 4 | black | 1 |
| 11 | 4 | white | 0 |

In this case result would be 2 because

- item oid 1 has red active color AND color white active
- item oid 2 has red active color but black is inactive
- item oid 3 has red active color but no black or white
- item oid 4 has red active color AND color white active

Comment: You might want to look at doing COUNT( CASE WHEN __ = __ THEN ELSE END) statement or set of statements. Is the format you need the results in already set? Or do you have room to change how the data comes back?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if your statement makes a ton of sense. What does the color column look like?  How can a color be black and red at the same time?

Comment: The column names are just examples. The original table is much more complex but i condensed it down to concentrate on the question.

Comment: Sure, I can understand that, but in your example, you give color that's equal to two different things. You can also try a sub-query but that is relatively slow performance-wise. I'm not sure what kind of performance you expect

Comment: Let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: I am trying to talk through the problem with you to see if I can get a better understanding of the problem and point you in a better direction. What you're trying to do sounds like it could be done a couple of different ways

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () `count`
FROM test
WHERE oid IN (1,2,3,4)
  AND active=1
GROUP BY oid
HAVING SUM(color='red')
   AND SUM(color IN ('black', 'white'))
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31e404ec66fbf89cb1413041a3e58109

Comment: Looks like something is not working. I get multiple results where each has a to high count.

Comment: @Mike I have read the task inattentively paying excess attention to your query. Updated.

Comment: Thanks but OVER clause is only supported in MySQL 8.

Comment: Don't really get how `DISTINCT COUNT(*)` should help here: GROUP by `oid` should be enough to essentially drive the results to 4 rows max (with the given set of conditions).

Comment: @Akina silly but why not: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebb64088baa50c0eba33d678369d4e21

Comment: @Mike For 5.x - the best choice. I'd should use COUNT(1) in subquery in this case - but there is no difference. PS. Next time specify your server version in the question explicitly - while not specified we assume that you use actual, most recent, version.